# Can't seem to get my plugin class include to load?

Tags: 7

If I keep my plugin class in the mymodule.module, then the plugin works fine. However moving it out to mymodule.context.condition.inc prevents the condition from working.

I have added file[] entry to mymodule.info and I have added the following to my hook_context_plugins:

```
function mymodule_context_plugins() {
  $plugins = array();
  $plugins['mymodule_context_condition_bonus_discount'] = array(
    'handler' => array(
      'class' => 'mymodule_context_condition_bonus_discount',
      'parent' => 'context_condition',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'),
      'file' => 'mymodule.context.condition.inc',
    ),
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

As mentioned, if I shift the code into the .module file, and remove the 'path' and 'file' lines from hook_context_plugins, then the condition is recognized by context and runs without issue.

SOLVED:

Looks like my class definition should not have had a capital "C" in "Class". Quite frustrating since I'm using drupalcs which complains about the lower case "class".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my class definition should not have had a capital "C" in "Class". Quite frustrating since I'm using drupalcs which complains about the lower case "class".